# remove comments of minified css/js in django compressor

Tags: django, django-compressor

I have django-compressor in my project and i use this filters for minify:

```
'css': [
     'compressor.filters.css_default.CssAbsoluteFilter',
     'compressor.filters.cssmin.CSSMinFilter'
 ],
 'js': [
     'compressor.filters.jsmin.JSMinFilter'
 ]
```

that works correctly. but this not removed license comments like:

```
/*!
 * example plugin v1.1.9
 *
 * Copyright 2015-present me
 * Released under the MIT license
 *
 * Date: 2020-09-10 13:16:21
 */
```

i searched and i found that `cssmin` filter has arguments that removed them. but i think `django-compressor` not supported it.
also i think that i can with `COMPRESS_PRECOMPILER` config remove this comments.

Comment: I don't think you are allowed to remove license comments: https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/5122 You should always serve the file with the license included.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you're not allowed to remove these comments. The MIT license in particular includes this:

> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

So I'd say this is "by design".